# Example doAuthenticateUser request message in CUCM 8.5 AXLAPI

Tags: java, c#, soap, cisco, cisco-axl

The WSDL supplied by Cisco for the their AXLAPI web service is not consumable by WCF Add Service Reference or ASMX Add Web Reference - it produces code that blows up in the Xml Serializer

Apparently the WSDL works fine from Java toolkits

I only need to use one operation on the web service - doAuthenticateUser. Does anyone have an example request message so I can see what I have to build to send a message that gets accepted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this response from the Cisco forums so to complete this:

Sample Request:

```
POST https://10.88.131.141:8443/axl/ HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "CUCM B ver=8.5 doAuthenticateUser"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Content-Length: 444
Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpjaXNjbyExMjM=
Host: 10.88.131.141:8443



<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:doAuthenticateUser sequence="1">
         <userid>cupuser1</userid>
         <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
         <password>password</password>
<!--         <pin>?</pin> -->
      </ns:doAuthenticateUser>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and a response for good measure

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONIDSSO=583F6C1C226B2F4A601CA578577404B5; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=F4A215575091DB7A443F6179168AC897; Path=/axl; Secure
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 373
Date: Fri, 20 Jan 2012 23:30:03 GMT
Server: 

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   
<soapenv:Body>
    <ns:doAuthenticateUserResponse xmlns:ns="http://www.cisco.com/AXL/API/8.5">
        <return>
          <userAuthenticated>true</userAuthenticated>
          <code>0</code>
          <daysToExpiry>0</daysToExpiry>
        </return>
    </ns:doAuthenticateUserResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```